# For how much time one should sleep according to Hindu scriptures?

Tags: sleep

According to Hindu scriptures , how much time per day a normal person should devote towards sleep ?

Comment: It was read somewhere (can't recall exactly where but am sure of it) that one should never sleep in daytime in order to avoid the displeasure of Surya Deva. This means that one should rise before sunrise, avoid naps in the afternoon & sleep only after sunset.